# Set a UIView to NILL from inside itself?

Tags: ios, release, null

I am creating an "Alert" view that will pop to the user in my app.

It has a button for closing it by calling:

```
[self removeFromSuperView];
```

I wish to set the view to nil when it closed so it will release. but

```
self=nil;
```

Is not legal.

How can I do that from the view itself without delegation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any other strong reference to the view, the view will be automatically deallocated for you under ARC.

Comment: @shannoga To be fair... nhahtdh answered first, I just was writing my answer and looking into the documentation at the same time :)

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation you don't have to worry. If the superview is not nil it will release the view after the call. Here is the relevant part:

> If the receiver’s superview is not nil, the superview releases the
>   receiver. If you plan to reuse a view, be sure to retain it before
>   calling this method and release it again later as appropriate.

Comment: Hey, since you said. like your honesty :)

Comment: @shannoga _To Caesar What Is Caesar's_ :)